# Start and run CANoe from Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, can-bus, capl, canoe

Is it possible to start and run Vector CANoe from the Command Prompt and/or by using any other external script?

Answer (score 2):

This document tells you how to control CANoe from C++, C# etc. This by making use of the CANoe as a COM Server utilities.
http://www.vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-AND-1-117_CANoe_CANalyzer_as_a_COM_Server.pdf

Answer (score 2):

CANOE simply loads a .cfg configuration file. For Jenkins, I am using the Visual Basic script and using this loading particular configuration file.

In this was it bypasses the *"I accept"* and other windows and loads the desired configuration also also using same kind of VB script you can close the application.

```
'ToStart CANoe_Start.vbs

Set App = CreateObject("CANoe.Application")   
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
dim CANoe_config    
CANoe_config = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("."), "<target.cfg>")

App.Measurement.Start()
```

After that you can add the operations in Jenkins jobs; to close the same appilcation use:

```
'ToStop CANoe_Stop.vbs
Set App = CreateObject("CANoe.Application")
App.Quit()
```

This worked for me. You can call the vbs's over command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to run Vector CANoe from an external script. The following VBS script code shows the various possibilities to start CANoe and to react on events within CANoe

```
' Creates and returns a reference to CANoe Application.    
Set App = CreateObject("CANoe.Application")
Set Measurement = App.Measurement
Set Logging     = App.Configuration.OnlineSetup.LoggingCollection(1)
Dim TestFunction, IsRunning
Wscript.ConnectObject Measurement, "Measurement_"

For Count = 1 To 5
    Logging.FullName = "C:\CANWIN" & Count & ".ASC"
    StartMeasurement()
    MsgBox "Press [Ok] to start the next 
    Measurement...", vbSystemModal
    Measurement.Stop
Next
MsgBox "Logging script done..."

While IsRunning
  On Error Resume Next
  TestFunction.Call(CDbl(Second(Time)))
  Wscript.Sleep 1000
Wend
  Wscript.DisconnectObject Measurement

Set Measurement = Nothing
Set App = Nothing

Sub Measurement_OnInit()
  Set TestFunction = 
  App.CAPL.GetFunction("TestFunction")
End Sub

Sub Measurement_OnStart()
  IsRunning = True
End Sub

Sub Measurement_OnStop()
  IsRunning = False
End Sub

Sub StartMeasurement()
  IsRunning = False
  Measurement.Start
  Count = 0
  While Not IsRunning
    Wscript.Sleep 100
    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = 10 Then
      MsgBox "Failed to start measurement!"
      Wscript.Quit
    End If
  Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is. You should go in Help - > Content - > CANoe - > Overview.

There will be every single info you need on how to use the command prompt with CANoe and its modules.

Comment: I should add that FDX is also a good choice. You can make an Ethernet application that remotely controls some parts of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced applications, CANoe is implemented as a COM-server and can be communicated with using that interface. CANoe's built-in help chapters will help you getting started.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to start and run Vector CANoe from the Command Prompt

By any means, yes it is. The trivial way to do that is to open a new Command Prompt instance (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, enter "cmd", hit return to run it) and provide the full path to your CANoe executable file. For instance, on CANoe v.10.0, x64, that would default to: `C:\Program Files\Vector CANoe 10.0\Exec64`, but on your system this might vary.

A more elegant way would be to add this path to your Windows Environment Variables Path. Now you are able to just open a Command Prompt and type the name of the executable and run it. Remember, for CANoe x64 that would be `canoe64`

> Is it possible to start and run Vector CANoe from the Command Prompt *and load a specific configuration?*

Yes. Just provide the path to the configuration as argument to your call, e.g.

```
canoe64 "D:\Documents\SomeProject\myConfig.cfg"
```

Mandatory regulation popups are displayed in both scenarios.